# COblist to array

Tags: c++

I have a COblist with controls like radiobutton etc. And now I want to create a CWnd* array from that list.

Obviously I can't do like this, `Cwnd* controls[controllerList.GetSize()];`, since the array wants a constant value.
But is there any simple way around this?

And by simple i mean any other way then create it with a small constant value, fill the array, create a new with the size + constant value and copy the content and so on.

Comment: Use `std::vector<CWnd*>`.  And really, why use `COblist` as opposed to `std::list`?

Comment: I'm working with a pretty old system and there is just no time to change things like this.

Comment: Wait -- this is a *new* issue, right?  The `std::vector` class exists even in Visual Studio 6.0 and maybe even 5.0.  What are you changing if you're encountering this issue for the first time?

Comment: Writing new functionality with old classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::vector<CWnd*>`:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<Cwnd*> controls(controllerList.GetSize());
//...
```

You now have a dynamic array of `CWnd*`.

Also, unless you're maintaining legacy MFC code, there is little reason to use the MFC containers over the STL containers.  For example, use `std::list` over `CObList`.  Even Microsoft doesn't use the MFC containers, as noted in this exchange:

[MFC Collection classes used only for backward compatibility](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?391319-RESOLVED-MFC-Collection-Classes)

Comment: *"Even Microsoft doesn't use the MFC containers"* - A blunt statement. And wrong, too. The MFC containers are used throughout the MFC, and they do surface at the interface as well (e.g. [CDocTemplate::GetFirstDocPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c62hz68d.aspx) and [CDocTemplate::GetNextDoc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48a8a7at.aspx)).

Comment: I'll take the word of  Ronald Laeremans, as stated in the link above.